# Steps for changing primary key from int to URI in live production SQL Server database without down time

Tags: sql-server, api-design

We have a service which uses the integer of a resource in another service as the primary key for the aggregate root.

It's been decided since this resource is not something we own we should store and use its absolute URI as the primary key.

The problem is that the service and database are live and there is another service using the contract. There is also a foreign key constraint on the existing primary key.

My questions are:

- Are the reasons for changing the primary key valid and what are the benefits?
- What are the steps to safely do this in the production environment without downtime?

Comment: I can't really see any benefit from doing this. Presumably the reasoning was originally to have it reference another table, in case the Uri changes. Now I'm assuming someone has decided the Uri most likely won't change, so extra reference table is not needed. I don't think this warrants a complex production change. There seems no disadvantage to keeping it as is.

Comment: I agree. There are _good_ reasons to replace external keys with surrogate keys.

Comment: Is the PK also the clustered index on the table? If so, making this change seems like a bad idea. Specifically, a clustered index should be narrow and monotone, neither of which a URI PK would be.